# Why is the output current on PSU different than that of a coin battery?

Tags: circuits

I have arranged two circuits (LED dimmer circuit usinga  potentiometer) on Tinkercad.

Why are the ammeter readings in both the cases different despite providing the same voltage?

[image: Tinkercad arrangement]

Comment: Try measuring the voltage across the coin battery when current flows and see what happens.

Comment: Maybe it's modeling the internal equivalent resistance of the battery? As you draw more current the battery's voltage drops, in real life. Coin cells are not theoretically perfect voltage sources.

Comment: Try drawing a proper schematic.

Comment: Typical CR2032 lithium coin cell cannot provide 12mA continuous drain; Energizer's CR2032 datasheet only claims 0.19mA typical continuous drain (at 2.9V), and their typical pulse duration tests 6.8mA (at 2.7V, 2 seconds, 12 times per day). I'm not sure how tinkercad models this battery's practical limitations. Also, practical current meters have some voltage drop ("burden voltage") due to their internal resistance. Try adding some voltmeter probes, I expect this will reveal the 3V battery voltage is not really 3V.

Comment: @markU that's patently false. The 0.19 constant drain and 6.8mA pulse ratings are for a given "reasonable/nominal" life span. Anyone that's ever powered an led off a cr2302 can tell you it's perfectly capable of 10s of milliamps for constant draw over 24 hours.

Comment: He did not measure the loaded battery. My CR3032 battery measures 3.396V with no load. With a 200 ohms load its voltage measures 0.77V and is dropping. 3V/200 ohms makes 15mA. 0.77V/200 ohms makes only 3.85mA.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption of same voltage is false, and because a battery with load on it will output less than 3V, the current is also less.

All voltage sources in real world are not ideal, they have series resistance. Coin cell batteries have much larger series resistance than a lab power supply so coin cell batteries can't output a lot of current to a load without significant voltage drop.